# Were Eurasia and Eastasia ever allied against Oceania?

Tags: george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

In Orwell's *1984*, the world is divided into three superpowers: Oceania (roughly equal to the Americas, Australasia, and Britain), Eurasia (roughly equal to the Soviet Union and mainland Europe) and Eastasia (roughly equal to China). At any given time, it seems that Oceania is either allied with Eurasia against Eastasia or allied with Eastasia against Eurasia, creating a global state of perpetual war, which helps to keep the citizens constantly riled up in nationalistic fervour.

Curiously, it seems that the isolated one among the three superpowers is always either Eurasia or Eastasia. **Is there any indication, from what we see in the book or from Winston's memories, that Eurasia and Eastasia are ever allied against Oceania?**

(Another question would be whether Eurasia and Eastasia even exist at all, or if the whole war, together with Goldstein's book, is just a myth created to help control the populace. But that's a separate question, not part of this one.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the book has to say:

> [Goldstein] was an object of hatred more constant than either Eurasia or Eastasia, since when Oceania was at war with one of these Powers it was generally at peace with the other.

That word "generally"  implies "not always". We can conclude that there have been rare time when they were at war with both other powers.

It doesn't necessarily mean that the opposing powers were *allied*, as such.